# XMLvalidation using Soap UI

Tags: soapui, xml-validation

I have been asked to validate an XML file using SOAPUI. Does anybody know if this is possible? I cannot find anything helpful in the Internet.

The validation needs to be done using an xsd file.

Any help useful!!!!!

Comment: What exactly do you need to validate? If you want to validate a SOAP response from a webservice soapUI offers the possibility to check if the response is matching the XSD. Do you have some more information?

Comment: I want to do a simple XML validation. I used to do it with XML Spy but I was asked to find a way to do it with SOAP UI as well. I have an XML file, an xsd file and I want to validate it

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to verify the response whether it is matching with the XSD, there is a option called Schema Compliance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Contains' assertion to validate xml tags